# Problems with a simple UDP listener

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp, wireshark

I used the very basic sample code here - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/92846ccb-fad3-469a-baf7-bb153ce2d82b/ - to create 2 console applications. One sends data via UDP, the 2nd application just receives and displays it. I did that on port 5115 and it all works fine. The sender sends random strings to 127.0.0.1:5115 and the listener receives it correctly.

We have a device that sends UDP packets to the same PC that I've been playing on, on port 5115. And using the same listener code, I receive absolutely *nothing* on it. What makes it weird is that Wireshark running on the same PC sees the packets just fine:

[image]

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I receive 0 bytes on the same port Wireshark is seeing all this data! COuld you please offer some suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sigh* The issue was the windows firewall. I didn't know Wireshark intercepts packets before the local firewall. 3 days down the drain...haha!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're sending packet at the loopback addresse "127.0.0.1". It works fine when you run you both the Listener and Sender application on the same machine. But when you run the sender on some other device and the listener on a separate device, the communication fails.

**Try changing loopback address in the Sender's application to the Listener Machines's IP Address**

You can find out the IP Address of listener by going to Command Prompt on your Listener's Machine. Type "ipconfig" and press Enter. In the output you'll see some IPv4 Address. Try changing "127.0.0.1" to this IPv4 address.

Comment: I just did that - changed 127.0.0.1 to the IPv4 IP address and the same port on my sender program. However the same thing's happening, my UDP listener program can still read it. ANother curious thing is that whatever my sender program sends, isn't captured by Wireshark...? Why would that be happening?